# How can I pass the file names to xargs and truncate them?

Tags: shell-script, ssh, xargs, tee

I have to write a script which will ssh into servers and truncate log files.

My script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

for server in $(cat c10_servers.txt); do
    ssh $server "ls /var/log/hello grep -i hello.log. | echo "" | xargs echo "" | sudo tee"
done
```

This just displays the names of files, I want to know what mistake I'm making as this is not working.

Comment: Put the entire command you're sending over `ssh` into single-ticks (`'`), as you have double-ticks (`"`) in the pipeline.

Comment: Why `sudo tee` with no argument?  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thats what i am confused with , should i give two `xargs` one for `echo` and one for `tee`?

Comment: @DopeGhoti It does not work with single ticks too.

Comment: @Wildcard I want these ls'ed file to truncated so I when doing manually goes to server and do 
     ` echo "" | sudo tee file_to_be_trucated.txt`
So I was trying to use xargs to pass file names.

Comment: It may be that `tee` does not do what you think it does.  Your use-case is nonsensical.  When you say in your question's title "truncate", what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Also `echo ""` makes zero sense where it is as it *ignores* its stdin.  Do the files have to be *truncated* or could they just be *removed*?

Comment: Not to mention that `echo "" | sudo tee filename` will never truncate a file fully, but will overwrite it with a single newline character.  This command is really a mess; what are you *actually* trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want them to be truncated and as the command truncate is not in the server I tried using the echo and tee combination.I just want to make the size of file zero.

Comment: If you want to truncate them, why are you not using the `truncate` command?  Also, log file truncation/deletion is usually done by the `logrotate` daemon.  Is it not installed on your servers?

Comment: There are a thousand better approaches than this script.  You could use a configuration management tool (e.g. Ansible).  You could set up a cronjob on each server.  You could use `logrotate`.  Even just blindly adding disk space to all the servers would be a better solution (barely).

Comment: To overwrite a file is a new zero-byte file, use `>/path/to/file`; no `echo` or `tee` or anything else needed.

Comment: @DopeGhoti, depends on permissions.  He's using `sudo` which implies the files are owned by `root` (if his question can be said to imply anything sensible....)

Comment: No truncate is not there and I can't add disk space also.This is not my server I have to manage it for a while without modifications on it.

Comment: I really think this is an A-B problem here.  Is the problem that the rotated logs (e. g. `foo.log.1`) are getting too large?  `ssh -t user@host.example.com sudo gzip /path/to/logs/*.log.*`.

Comment: Yes they get too large but was suggested to perform this command on files.No gzip or else.And the guy whose server is that I can' t question him much.

Comment: How do you "manage a server without modifications on it"?  That doesn't actually have any meaning.  Truncating a file is a modification, obviously.

Comment: I meant to say in terms of installing tools.

Comment: If you can delete data from /var/log, you are root.  If you are root, you can install logrotate.

Comment: I had all the permission but owner of the server told me not to install anything on the server untill he returns.
Now he had returned back and taking care of his server.
Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of:

```
ls /var/log/hello grep -i hello.log. | echo "" | xargs echo "" | sudo tee
```

Try:

```
for f in /var/log/hello/*hello.log.*; do sudo truncate --size 0 "$f"; done
```

To send this over SSH, put it in *single quotes*, not double quotes:

```
for server in $(cat c10_servers.txt); do
  ssh "$server" 'for f in /var/log/hello/*hello.log.*; do sudo truncate --size 0 "$f"; done'
done
```

---

You can do this without the `truncate` command but the quoting gets uglier:

```
for server in $(cat c10_servers.txt); do
  ssh "$server" 'sudo sh -c '\''for f; do : > "$f"; done'\'' sudo-sh /var/log/hello/*hello.log.*'
done
```

If you can SSH as root directly the command is simpler:

```
for server in $(cat c10_servers.txt); do
  ssh -l root "$server" 'for f in /var/log/hello/*hello.log.*; do : > "$f"; done'
done
```

Comment: You are correct @wildcard but truncate command is not there in server.

Comment: @Rusty, there.  But really...what are you doing modifying (managing) servers that you aren't allowed to modify?

Comment: Actually with you guys I come to know i don't basically understand diffrence between truncating and using the command `echo "" | sudo tee `.I need to study these things.
And @Wildcard your each method works.
thanks a lot.

Comment: "truncate" is a GNU-core-utils specific command